# Data migration from Access 2007 to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, migration, ms-access-2007, upsizing

I have been asked to migrate data and queried from MS Access to SQL Server.

While using upsizing wizard, out of 73 tables 69 got upsized properly and the other 4 tables were skipped (with no data migrated, only structure got created).

The reason I could guess is all this 4 tables have a huge number of records (7500*100).

I googled and found that its a known issue in microsoft and solution was to set the query timeout registry to zero. I even did this. But still the export fails.

Can anyone help me with this? I need to meet my boss's deadline.

P.S: I tried deleting half data and that way it was success. This made me to decide data is the issue. Thanks for everyone in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Link the tables, copy the remaining data using insert statements and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have around 8500 rows Insert query for each row would be tedious i guess

Comment: You don't need to make an Insert query for each row.  You do an Insert Select query for the remaining rows; with a Where condition to exclude the rows that have already been transferred. You could even truncate the table and copy all the data in one big swoop.

Comment: THanks once again. But my table is now in MS access and how can i write n insert query in sql serveer pointing to this table??

Comment: You link the four SQL-Server tables in Access and then, you can manipulate them as if they were ordinary Access tables.